# Permissions required to create subscriptions on a mailbox folder while accessing GraphAPI without user

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I created an app with the Application Permissions `MailboxSettings.ReadWrite`.

I then built a Web API to create subscriptions to mailbox folders.

I am successfully able to get the Auth Token and listen to the test notification from the app. But when I try to create a subscription I get the following error:

```
{
     Code: ExtensionError
     Message: Operation: Create; Exception: [Status Code: Unauthorized; Reason: Unauthorized]
}
```

This is how I am creating a subscription:

```
var subscription = new Subscription
{
    Resource = $"users/{CurrentUserId}/mailFolders('Inbox')/messages",
    ChangeType = "created,updated",
    NotificationUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:NotificationUrl"],
    ClientState = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
    ExpirationDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow + new TimeSpan(0, 0, 15, 0)
};

var newSubscription = await graphClient.Subscriptions.Request().AddAsync(subscription);
```

My question is, which permissions does my App need to have create a subscription?

I am using Microsoft Graph access without a user.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service. I want to run my API unattended.

Comment: Try `Mail.ReadWrite` permission.

Comment: @JoyWang Just tried it, gives the same error.

Comment: According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0), the `Mail.Read` permission will be enough. Did admin consent the permission for the AD App?

Comment: Yup, that was the issue. Admin consent was not given, as soon as I gave the admin consent the issue was resolved. Thanks @JoyWang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0), the `Mail.Read` permission will be enough. You need admin consent the permission for the AD App, see this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#application-permissions-14).

[image]